# Wait for property in EmberJS on "server" side

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In Ember, you can reference a property in a template, and the template will wait for that property to be populated before rendering.

This works great for obtaining a list of entries, which are populated by an external REST endpoint:

```
App.ItemsListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            client: App.Client.create()
        }
    }
});
```

Where the Client constructor looks like:

```
App.Client = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        var _this = this; // For referencing in AJAX callback
        $.ajax({
            url: MY_API_URL,
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function(res) {
            _this.set('itemsList', parsedDataFromRes);
        });
    },
});
```

For my template that relies on the `itemsList`, this works great:

```
...
{{#each item in model.client.itemsList}}
      <tr>
...
```

However, I have another route for a statistics, in which I would like to do some calculations on the results of the request, and return *those* values to the template:

```
App.StatsPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var itemCount = getClient().get('itemsList').length;
        return {
            numItems: itemCount
        }
})
```

I realize this is a contrived example - I could query the `length` on the template and it would work fine - but you'll have to humor me.

The issue with the above example is that the `get('itemsList')` is likely to return an undefined value, based on the data race of rendering the template, and the AJAX response and property setter being called.

How can I "wait" for a property to become available in my JS (not template code) so that it can be used to provide a model for the template?

Is converting the `'itemsList'` property to a function returning a promise the most "Ember-Like" way of doing things? Would this heavily complicate my template logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a promise and do additional operation in the `then` function call.
For example you can do

```
App.StatsPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var itemCount = getClient().then(function(promiseResult){
           var itemCount = promiseResult.get('itemsList').length;
           return {
            numItems: itemCount
          }
        })
})
```

To use this however, you need to make sure that getClient returns a promise. I suggested you use `ic-ajax` (included in Ember). It's an abstraction over jquery `ajax` that returns promises instead of expecting success and error callbacks

Furthermore, I strongly suggest that you look into `ember-data` and try to build a backend compliant with the spec. This way, you have a nice abstraction for your data and it increase development velocity tremendously, since you don't have to worry about interaction with the backend.

Edit: Returning a promise instead of data will not impact your template logic. Ember will resolve the promise and the Ember run loop will update the template automatically when the value changes. What you might want to have though, is perhaps a default value or a spinner of some kind. However, this is probably something you would have done regardless of if your model was returning a promise or not.

Comment: If I alter the `getClient()` function to return a promise, how does this alter the logic on my template page?

Comment: @CraigOtis, I updated my post to answer your question. Don't hesitate to ask for more clarifications.